# Shorter version of string match in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
if (element.matches("class Int"))
      true
    else
      false
```

Is it possible to use a function like the *.getOrElse for Sets to have cleaner code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if(condition) true else false
```

is equivalent to just `condition`, so you can remove the `if` statement in your code and just use

```
element.matches("class Int")
```

Also note that your pattern doesn't actually contain any regex operators and `String.matches` matches the whole string, so the whole thing is equivalent to checking whether `element` is equal to `"class Int"`. So you don't actually need to use `matches` at all.

Comment: IntelliJ could have answered that one :)

Comment: @eivindw I'm using Netbeans and happy that it is working so far for Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you're thinking about. I don't see how it makes things better unless you have a for()-comprehension and want to stop on a condition:

```
Some("a".matches("b")).filter(t => t).getOrElse(false)
```